# Transfer packages from old to new version R studio

Tags: r

I am using a R studio 0.96.331 (and R 2.15.1) and wanted to install new version of the studio (0.97). But, I am a bit worried about whether I have to install all the packages that I downloaded in the old version of the studio. Is there a simple way to  transfer all the downloaded packages of old version into new one?

Comment: I don't think installing RStudio does anything at all to your R installation.

Comment: That's right. If you update `R` itself you'll have to install the packages again (unless you pointed to a [fixed library location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698269/how-do-you-change-library-location-in-r-under-windows-xp)). Updating RStudio makes no difference.

Comment: I've no idea why this got migrated from SO.

Answer (score 3):

When you update RStudio you don't need to worry about your R packages.  Those are completely separate from RStudio - which is shown by the fact that you can run R without RStudio at all.  So you don't need to worry about transferring packages since it is a non-issue.